# Display planner events each week from start date until end date

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I have been scratching my head for the past 2 days on this one - I need an expert eye!

Basically, I am trying to display planner events for drivers over a 1 week period until they are off. If the driver is off from the 10th Dec 2018 until 21st Dec 2018, then I want the driver to roll-over to the next day and have his/her name displayed until the end date. Right now the result is only displaying the driver for the current day and not recurring over every day.

Here's a sample data set:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS planner_events (
  planner_id INT(5) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  event_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,     
  event_start_date DATE,    
  event_end_date DATE,
  user_id INT(5) NOT NULL,  
  user_type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  date_created DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO planner_events (event_name, event_start_date, event_end_date, user_id, user_type)
VALUES ('Annual Holiday', '2018-12-12', '2018-12-16', 101, 'driver'), 
('Alex on leave', '2018-12-12', '2018-12-15', 102, 'driver'), 
('Reminder', '2018-12-13', '2018-12-13', 103, 'driver');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS drivers (
  driver_id INT(5) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  driver_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
  date_created DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO drivers (driver_id, driver_name)
VALUES (101, 'Alex'), (102, 'Tom'),(103, 'Trevor');
```

I have created an SQL Fiddle, but by default SQL Fiddle doesn't have the seq_0_to_999999 table stored. I am using the latest version of MariaDB.

[SQL Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c71e6/5)

You can copy the tables and the SQL statements from the above on your local machine, should you have MariaDB installed.

Basically, in the code, using the in_array function I will remove the drivers from the availability box if they are off on a given day. I am trying to achieve this through 1 query, where it retrieves empty days for the week or where the drivers are off. Currently, the query only works if there is an entry for the given day and the problem is, it doesn't carry over if the end date hasn't finished.

[image]

Here is a good example by executing the current query. If you look at the below screen, Mario is off until 01/01/2019, but days 19,20,21,22, and 23 are blank and don't say his name. Their maybe a need of a CROSS JOIN somewhere - thinking logically!

[image]

Any help would be appreciated and thank you for taking the timeout!

Comment: I fear you're conflating issues of data storage and retrieval with those of data display.

Comment: If you're still struggling, a desired result for a given set of parameters might be useful

Comment: I have just uploaded a view of the current system that I am dealing with and I have explained what I mean. I will aim to edit it to describe the result.

Comment: I have just added the result set; what it is outputting and what it should be doing.

Comment: The data set and the result set bear no relationship to one another

Answer (score 2):

I found the query in your fiddle a little hard to follow. But I think what you want is this:

```
select *
from planner_events e
join drivers d on d.driver_id=e.user_id
where e.event_start <= @enddate and e.event_end >= @startdate
  and e.user_type='driver'
```

Where @startdate is the first day of the period you are interested in and @enddate is the last date. If the size of the range is always the same, one week or whatever, @enddate could be replaced with a calculation.

This should give you the list of all drivers who have events which overlap the desired date range. If what you want is all drivers who DON'T have an event in that date range, then just reverse the date test.

Oh, and of course instead of "select *" you should list whatever fields you are actually interested in. I was just being lazy there.

*Update*

Ah, I see. You want the list of who is available on each day, not just who is available sometime during the week.

Okay, to the best of my knowledge, to do that you need a table with a record for each day. There are a variety of ways to create such a table, I don't know a way using standard SQL. If creating that table is the issue we can get into that, but let me assume it's not and that such a table exists and is called "workdays" and each record includes a date field "date1".

Then the query could be done like this:

```
select w.date1, d.driver_id, d.driver_name
from workdays w
cross join drivers d
where w.date1 between @start and @end
 and not exists (select * from planner_event 
   where event_start<=w.date1 and event_end>=w.date1 and user_id=d.driver_id and user_type='driver')
order by w.date1, d.driver_id
```

This gives a result set with a list of dates and available drivers, which you would then have to format into the table you want with code. If you're looking for the result set to have one column for each day and one row for each driver or some such, I'm sure we could do that, have to play around with it a bit more. I think it would be a messy query, with a subquery for each day.

*Update 2*

Ah. If we know that the period is a week, then we don't need the weekday table. We can do this:

```
select d.driver_id, d.driver_name,
  case when exists (select * from planner_events where '2018-12-31' between event_start_date and event_end_date and user_id=d.driver_id) then 'N' else 'Y' end as Monday,
  case when exists (select * from planner_events where DATE_ADD('2018-12-31', INTERVAL 1 DAY) between event_start_date and event_end_date and user_id=d.driver_id) then 'N' else 'Y' end as Tuesday,
  case when exists (select * from planner_events where DATE_ADD('2018-12-31', INTERVAL 2 DAY) between event_start_date and event_end_date and user_id=d.driver_id) then 'N' else 'Y' end as Wednesday,
  case when exists (select * from planner_events where DATE_ADD('2018-12-31', INTERVAL 3 DAY) between event_start_date and event_end_date and user_id=d.driver_id) then 'N' else 'Y' end as Thursday,
  case when exists (select * from planner_events where DATE_ADD('2018-12-31', INTERVAL 4 DAY) between event_start_date and event_end_date and user_id=d.driver_id) then 'N' else 'Y' end as Friday
from drivers d
order by d.driver_id
```

Comment: This would only work on a daily basis view and not a weekly view. I already have this query working for daily. The problem I am facing is, we need a way of every day showing drivers on and off throughout the week.

Comment: No, this works on a weekly view. Give the start and end date for the week. Any events that overlap the week will be included in the output. Try it or work through an example. Say the week is Dec 9 to 15. If an event is Dec 8 to 12, it will pass the test. If it is Dec 14 to 20, it will pass the test. Dec 8 to 16 will pass the test. But Dec 7 to 8 will not, nor will Dec 20 to 21.

Comment: I have just updated the post and there is an image I have uploaded - you will get what I mean.

Comment: I have just added the result set; what it is outputting and missing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a gentleman called Andriy (https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/6965/andriy-m), he has helped me in the past and he has answered this to what my expectation is. Credit to also @Jay for posting another answer to this problem.

Here is the right SQL Query:

```
SELECT sub.planner_start_date, COALESCE(d.driver_name, 'N/A') AS driver_name, e.planner_id, e.event_name, e.event_start_date, e.event_start_time, e.event_end_date, e.event_end_time
FROM
( SELECT
        '2018-12-30' + INTERVAL seq.seq DAY AS planner_start_date
     FROM
        seq_0_to_999999 AS seq
     WHERE
        seq.seq <= TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2018-12-30', '2019-01-05')
    ) as sub
LEFT JOIN planner_events AS e ON e.event_start_date <= sub.planner_start_date AND e.event_end_date >= sub.planner_start_date
LEFT JOIN drivers AS d ON e.user_id = d.driver_id AND e.user_type = 'driver'
```

Thank you everyone for all your help with this.

Comment: The seq bit seems a bit daft to me. Obviously, you're outputting the result in application code, so that seems like the logical place to handle the display aspects. Still, it's your party.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is all the query you need:

```
SELECT d.driver_id
     , d.driver_name
     , e.planner_id
     , e.event_name
     , e.event_start_date
     , e.event_end_date
  FROM drivers d 
  JOIN planner_events e 
    ON e.user_id = d.driver_id;
```

Everything else would appear to be a display issue - best resolved in application code.

Comment: This would not work, as there is a reason for having the CASE statement, user_id, and user_type.